# What is the fastest way to move a div within the dom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm a little lost on moving a div within the dom. I basically need to change the order of some divs. Should I remove it and then reinsert it somehow or is there a better way to just move it in the dom tree.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: No need to remove, `appendChild` will move it to the the new parent (if that's the case)

Comment: It's the same parent but just changing the order of some divs within that parent.

Comment: So use [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.insertBefore). No need to remove either.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but take a look at this plugin http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only need to move it, and don't need to make any reflow-triggering changes to the element with JavaScript, simply use `appendChild()`.

On the other hand, if you need to make changes to the element, update its properties or 'physical' dimensions that would trigger a document reflow, then it's worth removing it from the DOM making the changes and then reinserting with either `appendChild()` or `insertBefore()`.

Bear in mind there's already going to be one document reflow, simply by relocating the element, but if any other changes are to be made then try to do them 'behind the scenes' with the element/node as a documentFragment before reinserting.

References:

- [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.appendChild).
- [`insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.insertBefore).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to remove it, you can re-position the node by using `appendChild` or `insertBefore`, or jQuery methods just such as `insertAfter`, etc.

eg:

```
var newOrder = ['id2', 'id1', 'id4', 'id3'];
var container = document.getElementById('container');

for(var i = 0, l=newOrder.length; i<l; i++) {
    container.appendChild(document.getElementById(newOrder[i]));
}
```

This will move the nodes with ids `id*` to the end of container, but in the order defined in `newOrder`

Comment: And? I just said you *can* use jQuery methods.

Comment: @ddlshack: `insertBefore` is not jQuery; it's standard DOM.  `insertAfter` is the jQuery addition.